# Стиль иконок соц сетей на сайте

Tags: html, css

Как сделать, что бы при наведение на иконку все остальные иконки становились темнее, но все иконки изначально белые.

По типу:

Без наведения на иконку

[image: Без наведения на иконку]

С наведение на иконку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это то, что я сделал.

```css
body
{
    font-family: "Lato";
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.75em;
    text-transform: none;
    letter-spacing: .4px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(140,140,140,.9);
    background-color: #333;
}

/*HelloPreload*/
#hellopreloader_preload
{
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99999;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 1000px;
    background: #333 url(http://hello-site.ru//main/images/preloads/puff.svg) center center no-repeat;
    background-size:41px;
}

/*Social media icon*/

ul.menu 
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0%;
    left: 40%;
    list-style-type: none;
}
ul.menu li 
{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
}
ul.menu li a i.fa 
{
    font-size: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    color: rgb(153, 153, 153);
    position: relative;
    transition: all ease 0.2s;
}

ul.menu li a i.fa:hover 
{
    color: rgb(158, 158, 158);
}

ul.menu li a i.fa-twitter:hover
{
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

ul.menu li a i.fa-instagram:hover
{
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

ul.menu li a i.fa-twitch:hover
{
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

ul.menu li a i.fa-github:hover
{
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css">
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>iriya</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!--Main page-->
<!--Social media icon-->

<ul class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitch"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Вариант с CSS:**

```
ul.menu:hover li a i {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.75em;
  text-transform: none;
  letter-spacing: .4px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(140, 140, 140, .9);
  background-color: #333;
}


/*HelloPreload*/

#hellopreloader_preload {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99999;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 1000px;
  background: #333 url(http://hello-site.ru//main/images/preloads/puff.svg) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: 41px;
}


/*Social media icon*/

ul.menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0%;
  left: 40%;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}

ul.menu li a i.fa {
  font-size: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  color: rgb(153, 153, 153);
  position: relative;
  transition: all ease 0.2s;
}

ul.menu:hover li a i {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

ul.menu li a i.fa:hover {
  color: rgb(158, 158, 158);
}

ul.menu li a i.fa-twitter:hover {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

ul.menu li a i.fa-instagram:hover {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

ul.menu li a i.fa-twitch:hover {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

ul.menu li a i.fa-github:hover {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css">
  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>iriya</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!--Main page-->
  <!--Social media icon-->

  <ul class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitch"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

**Вариант с jQuery.** Этот вариант лучше тем, что элементы не меняют стиль, когда курсор находится между ними. В первом же варианте элементы меняют стиль, как только курсор наводим на родительский блок.

```js
$('ul.menu li a i').on({
  'mouseover': function() {
    $('ul.menu li a i')
      .css('opacity', '1')
      .not(this)
      .css('opacity', '0.2');
  },
  'mouseout': function() {
    $('ul.menu li a i').css('opacity', '1');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.75em;
  text-transform: none;
  letter-spacing: .4px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(140, 140, 140, .9);
  background-color: #333;
}


/*HelloPreload*/

#hellopreloader_preload {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99999;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 1000px;
  background: #333 url(http://hello-site.ru//main/images/preloads/puff.svg) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: 41px;
}


/*Social media icon*/

ul.menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0%;
  left: 40%;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}

ul.menu li a i.fa {
  font-size: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  color: rgb(153, 153, 153);
  position: relative;
  transition: all ease 0.2s;
}

i:hover+i {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

ul.menu li a i.fa:hover {
  color: rgb(158, 158, 158);
}

ul.menu li a i.fa-twitter:hover {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

ul.menu li a i.fa-instagram:hover {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

ul.menu li a i.fa-twitch:hover {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

ul.menu li a i.fa-github:hover {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css">
  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>iriya</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!--Main page-->
  <!--Social media icon-->

  <ul class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitch"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно добавить

```html
ul.menu:hover li a i
{
    color: rgb(100, 255, 255);
}
```

Цвет можно поменять как захочется